# Constrain inherited associated type in a protocol

Tags: swift, generics, protocols, associated-types

I would like to define a Swift protocol that is a also a sequence with an element that conforms to another, specific protocol. Ideally, I'd like to write something like this:

```
protocol A { 
  var container: Container { get }
}

protocol Container: Sequence where Iterator.Element: A {
  ...
}
```

Unfortunately, Swift doesn't currently allow where clauses in a protocol definition (and it also doesn't allow to use protocols with associated types as type constraints). Is there any way I can still do this? Containers (and ideally A's) should be able to have different backing implementation.

Edit: I know that I can move the sequence to a type-erased property of Container, which will solve all the problems at the expense of introducing unnecessary lexical overhead. Still, I'm interested in a solution which does not 'cheats' its way out of the type system.